# Hero transition across 2 pages using webviews - Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I'm trying to achieve Hero transition between two WebViews (same webviews/URL), using this as reference (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA-vLF_vnng) but that video just says that I have to use `GlobalKey` to make this works. but, I have no found an example how to make this with webviews, because I need the SAME state into 2 diferent widgets, the examples that I found, use the global key just to invoke some method or retrieve some data from the other widget.

Have somebody used Hero Transitions with WebView's?

All my attemps ends either 'Duplicate global key' or 'the second webviews reloads page'.

Thanks...

Comment: Not sure which widget you want to see between the transition. The whole webview widget..? What are the examples that you found. Please share them and some starting code to work with.

Comment: Yes, simple, the SAME webview across two views, just a simple google url for example, ... But, I see there is an error on flutter sdk and opened an issue on github about global keys on flutter webviews (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57969)